# With Mamba, pypy cannot find modules installed using pip?

Tags: python, pypy, mamba

I'm testing using pypy for speeding up the execution time of a Python script I wrote. To install the dependencies of the script, I used both pip (some modules I need are not available via anaconda) and Mamba.

When I run the script using `pypy script.py`, I get an error message saying that the modules I installed using pip are not found (example: `ImportError: No module named presidio_analyzer`). Why does this happen? And do you have suggestions on how to fix this?

I'm running the tests on OSX. I installed Mamba using [micromamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba#micromamba).

Comment: *How* did you use pip and mamba to install the dependencies? Did you run them like `pypy -m pip install ...` or some other way?

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you should:

1. Create a conda environment that contains python and pip.
2. Activate the conda environment
3. Run `pip install ...`
4. Run `pypy script.py`

When you run `pip install ...` using an instance of `pip` that is part of your conda environment, then the python packages also get installed into the conda environment.

Your conda environment should also be activated when you run `pypy script.py` so that the `python` binary within the conda environment is utilized along with the packages you `pip` installed.